# Convert List<Authority> to Collection<GrantedAuthority> in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

My case is that i have a method that takes Collection and i have the value as a list
when i tried to add the list value into collection parameter it doesn't work, so should i cast it ?

**UPDATE:**
when i tried to create:

```
new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
                user.getAuthorities());
```

**where user.getAuthorities() returns an arraylist of my defined Authority object**

above code gives error that the **constructor is undefined**, when i add collection casting it works fine.

> ***org.springframework.security.core.userdetails*** 
>   ***Class User***
>
> ***Constructor***

```
User(java.lang.String username, java.lang.String password, 
boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, 
boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, 
java.util.Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? List **IS** Collection. Anywhere you could use Collection, you should be able to use List.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code? What is the error message you get? "doesn't work" is too vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc of the User constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html#User%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20java.util.Collection%29) tells you that the last argument must be a `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>`. So, you ArrayList will be accepted if it's an `ArrayList<Something>`, where `Something` is `GrantedAuthority` or a class which implements `GrantedAuthority`.

You still haven't told us what was the exact type returned by the method `user.getAuthorities()`. Do you understand Generics? Have you read the [Java tutorial about generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)?

Comment: you are right, i was adding list<Authority> not a list of GrantedAuthority, so i had to convert it as follows: `public Collection<GrantedAuthority> setUserAuthorities(List<Authority> auths) {

  List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
  for (Authority auth : auths)
   grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(auth.getName()));
  return grantedAuthorities;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

A `List` already *is* a `Collection` since it's a sub-interface of `Collection`.

If you have a variable of type implementing `List` (e.g. `ArrayList`), you can use it anywhere a `Collection` is expected. No conversion will be necessary, not even an explicit type cast.

Comment: when i tried to use list in a collection parameter it doesn't work.

Comment: please take a look at above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection<SomeClass> collection = list; //Where list is a List<SomeClass>
```

However, List already is collection, so actually no conversion is required.

Comment: please take a look at above code.